# How do I find out if a key exists in a multi-dimensional list in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list populated list populated like so

```
record.append([key, value1, count1, value2, count2])
```

but when I use the built in in function it does it not work.

```
if k in record
```

what's the most elegant way to search a multi-dimensional list in Python?

Comment: Try `.extend()` instead of `.append()`

Comment: why? i want each record to be within it's own row, not make one giant continuous list.

Comment: Have you considered using a dictionary instead of a list of keys and values?

Answer (score 2):

To search for a key in a list of list you need to search inside those inner lists:

you can use `any` here:

```
any(key in x for x in record)
```

or if your key is always at the first index then this will also work:

```
any(key == x[0] for x in record)
```

or use `list.extend` to append individual items to the list(instead of whole list), then your method will work fine.

Comment: I would probably just use `key==x[0]` ... but yeh (+1)

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator
if key in map(operator.itemgetter(0),records): ...
```

is the method I would use probably , or the more efficient method that will short circuit without iterating the whole list(per Ashwini's comment) ...

```
import operator,itertools
if key in itertools.imap(operator.itemgetter(0),records): ...
```

but really I think what you actually want

```
def findRecord(key,records):
    for r in records:
        if r[0] == key: 
            return r

print findRecord("some_key",records)
```